# Output is incorrect can you nest if statement into loops for array calculation?

Tags: c#, arrays, output

Here is the full source code It is not outputting the correct persons that make the most and the least. My best guess is the if statement inside the loop for calculations on pay if the person makes works over 40 hours. Code is simple learning C#. What is the best way to fix this.... sorry I know this is a probably a simple issue i'm missing. COMMENTS TO LABEL

```
{
class Program
{
    const double FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION = .10; //Federal Tax 10% of Gross Income
    const double STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION = .05;   //State Tax 5% of Gross Income
    const int    HOURS_OVERTIME = 40;         //# of Hours Needed For Overtime Pay Rate
    const double OVERTIME_PAY_DIFF = 1.5;     //150% of Normal Pay

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int MAX_LIST_VALUE;  //How Many Workers There Are For Array Limit.

        Write("How Many Workers Are Currently Working? ");                  //Asks For User Input # Of Workers
        MAX_LIST_VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        string[] workerName = new string[MAX_LIST_VALUE];          
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            WriteLine("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");        //Asks For User Input For Worker's Names
            workerName[i] = ReadLine();  
        }
        double[] workerWages = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            WriteLine("Please Enter " + workerName[i] + "'s Hourly Wage: "); //Asks For User Input For Worker's Wage
            workerWages[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        }
        double[] workerWeeklyHours = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Write("How Many Hours Has {0} Worked This Week? ", workerName[i]); //Asks For User Input For Hours Worked
            workerWeeklyHours[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        }
        double[] workersRegularPay = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerGrossIncome = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerStateTaxAmount = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];                //All Calculation Arrays
        double[] workerFederalTaxAmount = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerNetIncome = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerOvertimeHours = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        double[] workerOvertimePay = new double[MAX_LIST_VALUE];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            if (workerWeeklyHours[i] > HOURS_OVERTIME)                                                    //If Hours # is > 40.
            {
                workerOvertimeHours[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] - HOURS_OVERTIME;
                workerOvertimePay[i] = workerOvertimeHours[i] * (workerWages[i] * OVERTIME_PAY_DIFF);
                workerGrossIncome[i] = workerOvertimePay[i] + workersRegularPay[i];                   
            }
            else
            {
                workersRegularPay[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
                workerGrossIncome[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
                workerStateTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION;
                workerFederalTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION;
                workerNetIncome[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] - workerFederalTaxAmount[i] - workerStateTaxAmount[i];
                workerOvertimePay[i] = 0;
                workerOvertimeHours[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        WriteLine("\nNAMES ARE BLUE.");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        WriteLine("HOURLY WAGES ARE DARK YELLOW.");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
        WriteLine("HOURS WORKED ARE DARK CYAN.");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        WriteLine("NET INCOMES ARE GREEN.");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        WriteLine("There Are " + MAX_LIST_VALUE + " Workers!");  //Echo Of All Data Entered & Calculated For Workers
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            WriteLine("\nWorker's Name: " + workerName[i]);
            WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Hourly Wage: " + workerWages[i].ToString("C"));
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Hours Worked This Week: " + workerWeeklyHours[i]);
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Regular Pay: " + workersRegularPay[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Gross Income Pay: " + workerGrossIncome[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s State Tax Amount: " + workerStateTaxAmount[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Federal Tax Amount: " + workerFederalTaxAmount[i].ToString("C"));
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Net Income: " + workerNetIncome[i].ToString("C"));
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Overtime Hours: " + workerOvertimeHours[i]);
            WriteLine(workerName[i] + "'s Overtime Pay (if any): " + workerOvertimePay[i].ToString("C"));
        }
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        WriteLine("\nPress Enter To Continue For The Worker's That Earned The Least & The Most.");
        ReadLine();

        int minIndex = 0;
        string workerLeast = "null";
        double workerRegularPayLeast = 0,
               workerGrossIncomeLeast = 0,
               workerOverTimeLeast = 0;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        string workerMost = "null";
        double workerRegularPayMost = 0,
               workerGrossIncomeMost = 0,
               workerOverTimeMost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)         //Calculation For Worker That Made The LEAST
            if (workerGrossIncome[i] < workerGrossIncome[minIndex])
            {
                minIndex = i;
                workerLeast = workerName[i];
                workerRegularPayLeast = workersRegularPay[i];
                workerGrossIncomeLeast = workerGrossIncome[i];
                workerOverTimeLeast = workerOvertimePay[i];
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < workerGrossIncome.Length; i++)         //Calculation For Worker That Made The MOST
            if (workerGrossIncome[i] >= workerGrossIncome[maxIndex])
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                workerMost = workerName[i];
                workerRegularPayMost = workersRegularPay[i];
                workerGrossIncomeMost = workerGrossIncome[i];
                workerOverTimeLeast = workerOvertimePay[i];
            }
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;  
        WriteLine("\nThe Worker That Earned The Least Is {0}.", workerLeast);
        WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        WriteLine("{0}'s Gross Income Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerGrossIncomeLeast.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Regular Pay Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerRegularPayLeast.ToString("C")); //Output For LEAST
        WriteLine("{0}'s Overtime Pay Was {1}.", workerLeast, workerOverTimeLeast.ToString("C"));
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        WriteLine("\nThe Worker That Earned The Most Is {0}.", workerMost);
        WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        WriteLine("{0}'s Gross Income Was {1}.", workerMost, workerGrossIncomeMost.ToString("C"));
        WriteLine("{0}'s Regular Pay Was {1}.", workerMost, workerRegularPayMost.ToString("C"));   //Output For MOST
        WriteLine("{0}'s Overtime Pay Was {1}.", workerMost, workerOverTimeMost.ToString("C"));
        ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        WriteLine("\nPress Enter To Exit! \nThank You!");
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

here is where i think the issue is..

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
        {
            if (workerWeeklyHours[i] > HOURS_OVERTIME)                                                    //If Hours # is > 40.
            {
                workerOvertimeHours[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] - HOURS_OVERTIME;
                workerOvertimePay[i] = workerOvertimeHours[i] * (workerWages[i] * OVERTIME_PAY_DIFF);
                workerGrossIncome[i] = workerOvertimePay[i] + workersRegularPay[i];                   
            }
            else
            {
                workersRegularPay[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
                workerGrossIncome[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] * workerWages[i];
                workerStateTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION;
                workerFederalTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION;
                workerNetIncome[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] - workerFederalTaxAmount[i] - workerStateTaxAmount[i];
                workerOvertimePay[i] = 0;
                workerOvertimeHours[i] = 0;
            }
```

Somewhere a Logic issue
Output Is:[Output end only missing console inputs and first output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLj5v.png)

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before _anyone_ can help you

Comment: Debug your code to identify the source of the problem. See: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). Also using a single array of a class type containing 10 properties would be much easier than using 10 arrays.

Comment: Your problem lies in the if block where you calculate the variables _workersRegularPay_ and following. When a worker has overtime hours you don't calculate the normal hours. The else block should be calculated also if the worker has overtime hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the calculation of the GrossIncome is done differently if a worker has overtime hours or not. In case of overtime the calculation is wrong because uses a variable *workersRegularPay[i]* not initialized and the else block is not executed at all leaving the worker with overtime hours with incomplete data

You should change the loop that calculates the variable *workerGrossIncome* to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
{
    // Calculate the overtime hours and pay (if any) for the current (i) worker
    if (workerWeeklyHours[i] > HOURS_OVERTIME)
    {
        workerOvertimeHours[i] = workerWeeklyHours[i] - HOURS_OVERTIME;
        workerOvertimePay[i] = workerOvertimeHours[i] * (workerWages[i] * OVERTIME_PAY_DIFF);
    }

    // Calculate the regular pay for the same worker 
    // but without the overtime hours
    workersRegularPay[i] = (workerWeeklyHours[i] - workerOvertimeHours[i]) * workerWages[i];

    // Now you could sum the regular pay and the overtime pay 
    workerGrossIncome[i] = workerOvertimePay[i] + workersRegularPay[i];

    // Other calcs to do for the same worker.
    workerStateTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * STATE_TAX_DEDUCTION;
    workerFederalTaxAmount[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] * FEDERAL_TAX_DEDUCTION;
    workerNetIncome[i] = workerGrossIncome[i] - workerFederalTaxAmount[i] - workerStateTaxAmount[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank You! make much more sense now  I knew it was related to the calculation of the regular pay getting "messed up" if they worked overtime. under 40 hours calculated fine. Thank You again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

C# is an object-oriented programming language.  You need to create a class to encapsulate all of this data and make sense of it.  Having all of these loosely-related arrays is a mess - your code is not reusable, data can't be changed easily if a worker gets a raise or a different schedule, and frankly is confusing to look and and to input data into.

It is better to create a Worker class like this (right-click on your project in your Solution Explorer, click Add, click Class to create a new class file and call it "Worker.cs"):

```
public class Worker
{
    // properties contain data for each worker
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal HoursPerWeek { get; set; }
    public decimal HourlyPay { get; set; }

    // this is your constructor.  Set your variables to initial values here
    public Worker(string WorkerName, decimal WorkerHoursPerWeek, decimal WorkerHourlyPay)
    {
        this.Name = WorkerName;
        this.HoursPerWeek = WorkerHoursPerWeek;
        this.HourlyPay = WorkerHourlyPay;
    }

    // use methods to return any calculated values
    public decimal GetWeeklyPay()
    {
        decimal NormalHours;

        if (HoursPerWeek <= 40.0)
            NormalHours = HoursPerWeek;
        else
            NormalHours = 40.0M;

        decimal OverTimeHours;

        if (HoursPerWeek <= 40.0)
            OverTimeHours = 0.0M;
        else
            OverTimeHours = HoursPerWeek - 40.0;

        // hourly pay up to 40 hours, 1.5 times hourly pay for overtime
        return (NormalHours * HourlyPay) + (1.5M * (OverTimeHours * HourlyPay));
    }
}
```

Now that you have your worker class, instead of populating a dozen confusing arrays, you just write a program to create instances of your worker class like this:

```
// in your Program.cs, create instances of your worker class like this:
List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name for employee:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter hours per week:");
    decimal hours = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter hourly wage:");
    decimal wage = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // this creates an instance of your worker class and adds it to the list
    workers.Add(new Worker(name, hours, wage));
}

// now you have a list of workers that you can sort using Linq or some other method:
var sortedWorkers = workers.OrderByDescending(w => w.GetWeeklyPay());

// and you can output them in order from most pay to least:
foreach (Worker w in sortedWorkers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker " + w.Name + " makes " + w.GetWeeklyPay().ToString() + " dollars per week!");
}
```

Comment: I agree classes would be much simpler to use.